# FluentValidation summary always displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I'm using FluentValidation form a form, and the Validation summary seems to be displayed at load time. I don't have anything that seems to submit the form automatically and in my controller, no validation check is made until the form is posted. Weird enough, validation seems to work perfectly when submiting.

ViewModel:

```
[Validator(typeof(SendMessageInputValidator))]
public class SendMessageInput
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string VideoUrl { get; set; }
    public string CultureName { get; set; }
    public bool VideoMode { get; set; }
}

public class SendMessageInputValidator : AbstractValidator<SendMessageInput>
{
    public SendMessageInputValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(s => s.Title)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("TitleRequired".Translate("MCN"));
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Detail(Guid entityId, string cultureName)
    {
        var entity = _sendMessageRepository.Get(entityId);

        if (entity == null)
            throw new HttpException(404, "Not found.");

        return View(new SendMessagePageViewModel
                        {
                            NodeId = entity.NodeId,
                            Name = entity.Name,
                            Title = entity.Title,
                            Content = entity.Content,
                            BrowserTitle = entity.BrowserTitle,
                            MetaDescription = entity.MetaDescription,
                            MetaKeywords = entity.MetaKeywords,
                            SendMessageInput = new SendMessageInput { VideoMode = true }
                        });
    }

    public ActionResult SendMessageForm(SendMessageInput input)
    {
        input.CultureName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
        return PartialView(/*input*/ new SendMessageInput());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendMessage(SendMessageInput input)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(input.CultureName);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Redirect(Utilities.GetUrl(Constants.NodeIds.MyProfile));
        }

        var entity = _sendMessageRepository.Get(Constants.NodeIds.MentorQuestionForm);

        if (entity == null)
            throw new HttpException(404, "Not found.");

        return PartialView("Detail", new SendMessagePageViewModel
                                         {
                                             NodeId = entity.NodeId,
                                             Name = entity.Name,
                                             Title = entity.Title,
                                             Content = entity.Content,
                                             BrowserTitle = entity.BrowserTitle,
                                             MetaDescription = entity.MetaDescription,
                                             MetaKeywords = entity.MetaKeywords,
                                             SendMessageInput = input
                                         });
    }
```

View (Main):

```
 @Html.Action("SendMessageForm", "SendMessage", Model.SendMessageInput)
```

View (Partial):

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "ValidationSummaryHeader".Translate("MCN"))  
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendMessage", "SendMessage", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="Formulaire">
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, "Title".Translate("MCN"), true)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { maxlength = 200, @class = "TxtBox" })
        </p>

        @if (Model.VideoMode)
        {
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VideoUrl, "VideoUrl".Translate("MCN"))
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VideoUrl)
            </p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Content, "Message".Translate("MCN"))
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Content, new { @class = "TxtArea" })
            </p>
        }

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CultureName)

        <input type="submit" value="@("Submit".Translate("MCN"))"/>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you're first going to display the Detail view, you are newing up a `SendMessageInput`, which as it is new will have an empty `Title` by default.

When you are then calling through to the `SendMessageForm` action, you are passing it this new `SendMessageInput` with the empty title.  Thus during model binding it will be getting a model error, and hence when your partial view is rendered the ValidationSummary is displayed.

Have you tried using `Html.Partial` (or `Html.RenderPartial`) instead of `Html.Action`? This would render the form without any model binding taking place.

Comment: Great, going to try that! Thanks!

Comment: Well, tried will Partial AND RenderPartial, still the same result. It's weird =(

Comment: Ok, my bad. Had two forms in my project. One that had Html.ValidationSummer() OUTSIDE the using BUT with Html.Action... (this one you're looking at). And, another one with the Html.ValidationSummery() INSIDE the using, but was using Html.Partial ... SO... in conclusion, you have to get the Html.ValidationSummary() OUTSIDE the using AND use the Html.Partial. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Even if ngm's answer is a part of the answer, I wasn't able to make it work.

So, for anyone who's reading this in the future, here's how I did make it work:

- `@Html.ValidationSummary()` must be in the `@using` statement or it just doesn't show the validation summary.
- Using `@Html.Partial` or `@Html.RenderPartial` is considered a good pratice but won't prevent the summary to be displayed.
- I did solve my problem though using CSS. The validation summary is first rendered with a class `validation-summary-valid` and I applied a `display:none` to it. Once there are errors, the class is changed to `validation-summary-errors`.

There, you have it, and it's not even FluentValidation related, it's just the way the Html extension works.